# What image encoding does Aruco expect?

Tags: opencv, encoding, rgb, aruco

My application receives camera images which can have a `bayer_rggb8` encoding. Do I need to convert these images to `bgr8`/`rgb8`/`mono8`? Or can Aruco detect markers in bayer-encoded `cv::Mat`s?

I'm using Aruco 3.0.10. Below is the function I'm using.

```
    /**Detects the markers in the image passed
        *
        * If you provide information about the camera parameters and the size of the marker, then, the extrinsics of
     * the markers are detected
        *
        * @param input input color image
        * @param detectedMarkers output vector with the markers detected
        * @param camParams Camera parameters
        * @param markerSizeMeters size of the marker sides expressed in meters
        * @param setYPerperdicular If set the Y axis will be perpendicular to the surface. Otherwise, it will be the
     * Z axis
        */
    void detect(const cv::Mat& input, std::vector<Marker>& detectedMarkers, CameraParameters camParams,
                float markerSizeMeters = -1, bool setYPerperdicular = false);
```

I tried to just give it the `bayer_rggb8` encoded image, which seems to work (it detects markers). But I would like to know if this is supposed to work, or if I'm just lucky with my test image.

Left: Original image, wrongly displayed as brg8. Right: Image converted/color interpolated to BGR8 and annotated with marker. (The marker was detected on the left image.)
[image]

Comment: It would probably work pretty well on Bayer encoded images by accident, given that a Bayer RGGB8 image of black and white markers, reinterpreted as 8-bit greyscale, should look a lot like a 2x zoomed greyscale of the same scene. However, it would take 4 times the memory and be 4 times slower to process.  And there may be different color curves on the 3 channels, causing a checkerboard effect in the grayscale reinterpretation -- I'd have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It accepts either a `CV_8UC1` grayscale image (`mono8`) or a `CV_8UC3` color image (`bgr8`). It doesn't work on bayer-encoded mats.

---

When in doubt, check the source code.

You can see [aruco.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/src/aruco.cpp#L1111) that the first operation is converting the image to grayscale:

```
_convertToGrey(_image.getMat(), grey);
```

The function [`_convertToGray`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/src/aruco.cpp#L104) accepts a `CV_8UC1` (already ok) or `CV_8UC3` (converts to grayscale):

```
static void _convertToGrey(InputArray _in, OutputArray _out) {

    CV_Assert(_in.getMat().channels() == 1 || _in.getMat().channels() == 3);

    _out.create(_in.getMat().size(), CV_8UC1);
    if(_in.getMat().type() == CV_8UC3)
        cvtColor(_in.getMat(), _out.getMat(), COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    else
        _in.getMat().copyTo(_out);
}
```